# Groupby search first and last True values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd.Series with duplicated indices, and each index containing a set of booleans:

```
FA155    False
FA155    False
FA155    False
FA155    True
FA155    True
FA155    True
FA155    True
FA155    True
FA155    False
```

What I'm trying to do for each different index in an efficient way, is to keep only as True the first and last True values of the sequence, and set the rest to False. There can also be False values between those that are True.

So for this sample the result would be:

```
FA155    False
FA155    False
FA155    False
FA155    True
FA155    False
FA155    False
FA155    False
FA155    True
FA155    False
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: All your indices are `FA155` in this example. Are you sure this is right?

Comment: Yes, just that there are many values for each index.

Comment: Alright, now I got it ;} I thought you wanted to set to `True` the first value for index `FA155` but you want to *keep* `True` only the first and last `True` values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `loc` with `idxmax` with both your original `df` and your inverted `df`.

This will yield the index of your first and last `True` values. Just set the different indexes to `False` afterwards.

For example:

#### Setup

```
z = sio("""i    v
FA154    False
FA155    False
FA155    True
FA155    True
FA155    True
FA155    True
FA155    True
FA155    False
FA156    False
FA156    True
FA156    False
FA156    False
FA156    True""")

df = pd.read_table(z, delim_whitespace=True)

    i       v
0   FA154   False
1   FA155   False
2   FA155   True
3   FA155   True
4   FA155   True
5   FA155   True
6   FA155   True
7   FA155   False
8   FA156   False
9   FA156   True
10  FA156   False
11  FA156   False
12  FA156   True
```

#### `idxmax()`

Which is the same thing as getting your `df` and using `reset_index`. Then, get list of indexes for you first (`v1`) and last (`v2`) `True` values:

```
v1 = df.groupby("i").v.idxmax().values
v2 = df[::-1].groupby("i").v.idxmax().values
```

And use your logic:

```
df.loc[v1, "v"] = True & df.loc[v1, "v"]
df.loc[v2, "v"] = True & df.loc[v2, "v"]
df.loc[~df.index.isin(np.concatenate([v1,v2])), "v"] = False
```

The idea behind using `&` is not to accidentally set any `False` values to `True`.

Result:

```
>>> df.set_index("i")

        v
i   
FA154   False
FA155   False
FA155   True
FA155   False
FA155   False
FA155   False
FA155   True
FA155   False
FA156   False
FA156   True
FA156   False
FA156   False
FA156   True
```

Answer (score 1):

You filter True values and then you aggregate to find the first and last values. Then you can use loc to replace those values in df.
`df` is your dataframe. `col` is the name of your column with `True` and `False` values

```
df["nb"] = range(df.shape[0])
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

elem = (df[df[col]==True].groupby("index")["nb"].agg({ "first_True": 'first', "last_True":"last"})).values

indexes_to_False = sum(elem.tolist(), [])

df.loc[indexes_to_False, col] = False
```

Then you can drop the column `nb` and reindex if you wish

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the `diff` to get the group starting point , I am using `iloc` twice since you need keep the head and tail True

```
df1=df.copy()
df.loc[df]=df.astype(int).diff().ne(0)[df]
df=df.iloc[::-1]
df1=df1.iloc[::-1]
df.loc[df1]+=df1.astype(int).diff().ne(0)[df1]
df=df.iloc[::-1]
```